# Display most viewed post from last 30 days is not working correctly

Tags: loop, query

I've try several different loop to display the most viewed post from the last 30 days . . However its just showing the post from 30 dasy ago . . not from the last 30 days . . not the most viewed . . iF anybody can help me out  . .it will be fantastic, thank you =)

Here is my loop at the moment:

```
<ul>
<?php
function filter_where($where = '') {
    //posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=3&orderby=post_views_count&order=ASC');

while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<li><div class="tabber-image">

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumb'); ?></a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="tabber-text">
                        <?php 
                        //$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
                        //$short_title = $meta['maxmag_featured_headline'][0];
                        ?>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="main-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
```

ANy help would be amazing . .thank you for your time

EDIT ---

Last LOOP:

```
<ul>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

    $args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'  => '30 days ago'
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

     ?>

<li>

<div class="tabber-image">

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumb'); ?></a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="tabber-text">
                        <?php 
                        //$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
                        //$short_title = $meta['maxmag_featured_headline'][0];
                        ?>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="main-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                        </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

---

ORIGINAL CODE FROM PLUGIN:

```
<div id="tab2" class="tabber-content">
            <?php $popular_posts = new WP_Query('showposts=' . $popular_number . '&orderby=comment_count&order=DESC'); if($popular_posts->have_posts()): ?>
            <ul>
                <?php while($popular_posts->have_posts()): $popular_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="tabber-image">
                        <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumb'); ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tabber-text">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="main-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <p><?php echo excerpt(10); ?></p>
                        <div class="headlines-info">
                            <ul class="headlines-info">
                                <li>Posted <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' ago'; ?></li>
                                <li class="comments-icon"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--headlines-info-->
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!--tab2-->
```

Comment: Any reason why you didn't use the date_query and it's `after` parameter as described here? http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: What do you mean ? I didnt understand you sorry

Comment: You have filtered the where query (for all queries) and then run query_posts that is not recommended by any one. Any specific reason why you had to do things in this roundabout manner than using an instance of WP_Query which supports this kind of queries (from the last 30 days, etc) as you can see on the codex page I've posted?

Comment: Because I have a straightforward answer to your question but if you are forced to do it this way, it'd be useless for you.

Comment: Hi .. hm im not sur to understand, does thsi looks better ?

This one is not working also ) I jsut add in the edit of my post) just displaying the current month  post and not last 30 days :(. . . my query skills are quite low if you have any highlite .. . would be wonderfull, Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'  => '30 days ago'
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can't directly order by met_key's name, you need to use it the way it is above.

Comment: Ive edit the edit loop from my post . . I tried this one that you just recomended but it's not working correctly  .. just showing one post from today . . . :(

Comment: I forgot to change the `-30 days` to `30 days ago`. Try now.

Comment: :( Thank you for your time . .but it still display only one post :(

Comment: Oh, but I've only give you the query results. Did you loop through them? using `while($query->have_posts()):the_post();` and `endwhile;` Otherwise you'll only display one.

Comment: Thank you, I ve edit my last edit code, But this is displaying much more post ( Around 20, and by ascendant date, its not taking count of the post_view_count :(

Comment: Are you saying 20 instead of the 3 that's passed in the arguments or 20 total which is higher than the posts in the last 30 days? If your meta is not considered, are you sure that this is the exact meta key? Are you using a plugin or did you write the code for the meta yourself?

Comment: I mean 20 instaead of the 3     'posts_per_page' => 3,

I am sur about the meta, they are displaying like that . ..  .

Ive attach the original code of the plugin if it can be aeasier :( ? Realyl appreaciate all your time ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21571/discussion-between-saurabh-shukla-and-user3439889).